# How I can get values of headers of my table when I select a cell?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm working on application for booking rooms and I use Angular 2. I would like to select cell in my table and get values of vertical and horizontal headers, like "Room 1" and "9:00". I'm getting data for table's headers from server. This is my html code:

```
<div class="table">
<table class="schedule-table" *ngIf="titles && titles.length && intervals && intervals.length">
        <tr>
            <th class="vertical-header-cell"></th>
            <th class="horizontal-header-cell" *ngFor="let title of titles">{{ title }}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let interval of intervals">
            <th class="vertical-header-cell">{{ interval }}</th>
            <th class="body-cell" *ngFor="let title of titles"></th>
        </tr>
</table>
```

My css:

```
table {
width: 100%;
margin-top: 100px;
border-collapse: collapse;
}   

th {    
height: 60px;   
}

table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
}

.body-cell:hover{
background-color: green;
}

.vertical-header-cell {
width: 100px;
}
```

[My table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJldu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a `click` function

```
<th class="horizontal-header-cell" *ngFor="let title of titles" (click)="clickHeader(title,intervals)" >{{ title }}</th>

clickHeader(title: any, intervals: any){
   console.log(title + intervals)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but using this function I can get only title. I'd like to get "title" and "interval" like a coordinates of cell.

Comment: Yes, It hit me)) Thanks)